# How to read large data from file into MS chart control series in C#

Tags: c#, charts, stream

I'm a beginner in programming in C#.

I want to read large (>1GB) text file (containing values of a voltage readings in one single column) and display it on the MS control chart.

It works okay with small files (~50mb) but it gets stuck on files >300mb and even gives an out-of-memory exception for larger files.

I have ~30e6 values each like this one: "0.189312433308071".

Here's how im reading the data right now:

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string line;

int pointIndex = 0;


while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)  

{
    dataVoltage.Add(line);
    chart1.Series["Default"].Points.AddXY(pointIndex, Convert.ToDouble(line));
    pointIndex=pointIndex+1;

    }

sr.Close();
```

How can I successfully do this without waiting for minutes for file to load or not load at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your performance problems are entirely in adding values to your chart. I created a medium-sided file (~560mb) using the first line of main, then read it and summed its values. Took less than a minute.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace LargeReadWrite
{
    class Program
    {
        const string fileName = "D:\\PersonalDev\\stackoverflow\\largefile.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateLargeFile();
            ReadLargeFile();
        }

        static void CreateLargeFile()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                for (uint i = 0; i < 30000000; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(r.NextDouble());
                }
            }
        }

        static void ReadLargeFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                double total = 0.0;
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    total += Double.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.WriteLine(total);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run some performance profiling tools and decide if the chart is the right place to hold this, as holding that many values will eat as much memory as you need to hold. You may do better bucketizing the average of your results for every n readings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually the application requires to display the exact values on the chart. What I have in mind is to display an average foe each n values (as you said) initially. But as the user zooms in some particular area, the application should then add the exact values for that duration and it should remove them and display the same old average values when the user zooms out. But I really don't think I can do that, seems so complex.

Comment: It's not that complicated. In fact, if you're bucketing values, you can determine what buckets the zoom focuses on, then rebucketize those buckets. You're still going to be using quite a bit of memory, but it shouldn't choke your system trying to read or load values.

You can additionally put upper-lower bars around the average before the zoom is close enough to show the data you want. However, displaying 30 million individual dots on an object not meant for that kind of display will not work out.